# How to split a String without using an array?

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split a String.

I have been searching but I only found cases where `split` is used with an array, so for example if you have the string `"i love stackoverflow"` and use `split` , the output will be `[i,love,stackoverflow]`

Instead of that I have a string with this format `"URL_cars_es"` and I just want the `es` part of it, because I have multiple files into my database with different languages lets say I have `"URL_cars_it"` `"URL_cars_nb"` and so on. I just need to split and get only the `nb,es,it` so i can pass it to my `StorageReference` and get the different files

I am  getting `URL_cars_es` by using below code

```
selecteditem =  adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

and I also need to trim/split it to only `es`.

Comment: Will you always only want the last two characters of the string? You could use a substring function in this case.

Comment: You may also look for *regular expressions* and  `java.util.Pattern`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't wanted to use array/split. Then you can use [`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) (index of the last occurrence of given character) and then substring from that index position.

```
String s1   = "URL_cars_it";
int lastPos = s1.lastIndexOf('_'); // return the index of the last occurrence

s1 = s1.substring(lastPos + 1); // return `it`
```

Comment: thanks, will check this as correct as you were the first one answering

Comment: @IDroid let me know, if you have any specific requirement, where it doesn't fulfill as this is specific to your mentioned scenario.

Comment: its ok, i was just needing this because i was making a spinner with different elements from firebase database, but i just realised that i cant get from the storage the Locale language or the language that people are using because im doing another app to manage how users are interacting with the app. So i was looking for a workaround to get the different user languages , thanks for the help

Comment: @IDroid So, was it helpful ? or you have any other scenario ?

Comment: it was really helpfull and solved my problem, now with this one line i can get different information from different languages of how users are interacting with the app, thanks

Comment: @IDroid glad to know. :-)

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
String countryCode = es.split("_")[2] //only take the 3rd entry of the array
```

I do not have the `split()` implementation in my mind now, just guessing it should look like the above.

Comment: This is assuming the string **always** splits into 3 parts. If a different prefix is used this could produce an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @MichaelDodd this is absolutely correct. But he stated that his `String` does always look like that.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to remove `URL_cars_` using the [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method:

```
String str = "URL_cars_es";

System.out.println(str.replace("URL_cars_", ""));
```

Output:

> es